# Hindi contents are not displaying in jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am using following code in servlet

```
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.init(velocityProperties);
    Template t = ve.getTemplate( templateName );
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("fullname", fullname);
    context.put("fathername", fathername);    

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    t.merge(context, writer);

    String fetchedContents = writer.toString();
```

by this code i am fetching contents of velocity template. and set it with session.

```
session.setAttribute("fetchedContents", fetchedContents);
```

now on jsp page i am receiving value of `fetchedContents` by following code

```
String fetchedContents = (String) session.getAttribute("fetchedContents");
```

Now i want to print the value of `fetchedContents` on jsp page

```
<%=fetchedContents%>
```

but it is displaying in following format-

```
à¤à¥ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤à¤¯ à¤à¤° à¤à¤§à¤¿à¤à¤¾à¤°à¤¿à¤¯à¥à¤ à¤à¥
```

I am using `UTF-8` encoding on jsp page and have tried to change other encoding but did not find any solution. Please give me solution?

Comment: on your JSP page add this line above `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: Some where in flow you are not using UTF-8 encoding. You have to find that.

Comment: reply so that v know if ur issue gets solved

Comment: @Santino 'Sonny' Corleone i have added request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); on jsp page but having same problem.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao i have one jsp and one servlet and in both i have used utf-8 encoding. but still haven't got solution.

Comment: Thanks both of you. my problem has resolved. @SubirKumarSao you were right. i was calling getTemplate( templateName ) without encoding. But when i am calling getTemplate( templateName , "UTF-8" ) then contents are displaying.